# Modify text padding not image padding on menu

Tags: html, css

I have a sprite menu, and want to fix the padding, If I add pad the text is moved but also image...

```
#categories{width:1042px;height:170px;margin:15px 0px 0px 0px;}
#categorieMenu{background:url(http://hmimexico.com/categories.jpg) no-repeat;width:1042px;height:170px;margin:0;padding:0;background-size:100% 200%;}
#categorieMenu li,#categorieMenu a{height:170px;display:block;color:#000000; text-decoration:none;}
#categorieMenu li{ 
    float:left;   
    list-style:none;    
    display:inline; 
    text-indent:5px;        
    line-height:95%;    
    font-size: 25px;    
    color: #000;
    font: normal 25px "DroidSansBold", Calibri, sans-serif;
    /*how to add correct pad to adjust text as wanted image?*/
    }
#categorie_1{width:174px;}
#categorie_2{width:175px;}
#categorie_3{width:174px;}
#categorie_4{width:175px;}
#categorie_5{width:174px;}
#categorie_6{width:170px;}
#categorie_1 a:hover{background:url(http://hmimexico.com/categories.jpg) 0px -170px no-repeat;}
#categorie_2 a:hover{background:url(http://hmimexico.com/categories.jpg) -174px -170px no-repeat;}
#categorie_3 a:hover{background:url(http://hmimexico.com/categories.jpg) -349px -170px no-repeat;}
#categorie_4 a:hover{background:url(http://hmimexico.com/categories.jpg) -523px -170px no-repeat;}
#categorie_5 a:hover{background:url(http://hmimexico.com/categories.jpg) -698px -170px no-repeat;}
#categorie_6 a:hover{background:url(http://hmimexico.com/categories.jpg) -872px -170px no-repeat;}
```

I want to get womething like:
[image]

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DWx5H/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking to pad only the text included within the list item tags, you can select them like this:

```
#categorieMenu a {
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

You can adjust the padding as you see fit without affecting the padding of the image.

Answer (score 1):

move the padding in the anchors inside li's

```
#categorieMenu a{
    padding: 20px;  

}
```